# How to handle polymorphism when dealing simultaneously with multiples pointers of the base class?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, operator-overloading, overloading

The way I understand polymorphism for a c++ class, it allows for a class and its subclasses to be handled the same manner. So if I have multiple objects of a class and its subclasses and I store them in a vector of (smart) pointers of the base class, I can call any virtual method on them and it will work just fine.

```
class Dancer {
public:
    virtual void f() const { std::cout << "I am a basic dancer" << std::endl; }
};

class SkilledDancer : public Dancer {
public:
    void f() const { std::cout << "I am a skilled dancer" << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Dancer> > dancers;
    dancers.push_back(std::make_shared<Dancer>(Dancer()));
    dancers.push_back(std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Dancer>(std::make_shared<SkilledDancer>(SkilledDancer())));

    for(auto & dancer : dancers ){
        dancer->f(); //works fine
    }
}
```

But now I have an issue when I want this kind of behavior, when using operators or methods that deal with two objects. If a function takes in input two arguments of the base class, how do I take in account the fact that they may actually be objects of the derived class ?

```
class Dancer {
public:
    virtual void g( const Dancer & d ) const {  std::cout << "Let's do a basic dance" << std::endl;  }
};

class SkilledDancer : public Dancer {
public:

    //what should I do here ?

    void g( const Dancer & d ) const {  std::cout << "Let's do an advanced dance" << std::endl;  }
    //would overload Dancer::g but wrong because d is only a Dancer

    void g( const SkilledDancer & d ) {  std::cout << "Let's do an advanced dance" << std::endl;  }
    //doest not overload Dancer::g because different signature
    //so would never be called if dealing with two smart pointers of the base class
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto basic = std::make_shared<Dancer>(Dancer());
    auto advanced = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Dancer>(std::make_shared<SkilledDancer>(SkilledDancer()));
    basic->g(*advanced);    //OK
    advanced->g(*advanced); //seems good ...
    advanced->g(*basic);    //... but wrong
}
```

I have managed to find a workaround (code below), but it requires one additional member for the derived class, two additional function calls, and the function cannot be const anymore. So I am wondering if there is a better way to handle this.

In case I'm facing an XY problem, my actual problem is about matrices. I would like to have a matrix operator to multiply to matrices, but when dealing with two particular matrices (like triangular or symmetric, which are subclasses of the base matrix class), I would like to call another operator. Note that all types of matrices are stored as pointers of the matrix base class.

```
class Dancer {
public:
    virtual void g( const std::shared_ptr<Dancer> & d ) {  std::cout << "Let's do a basic dance" << std::endl;  }
};

class SkilledDancer : public Dancer {
public:
    SkilledDancer() : dummy_g(false) {}
    bool dummy_g;

    void g( const std::shared_ptr<Dancer> & d) {
        if( !dummy_g ){
            dummy_g = true;
            d->g(std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Dancer>(std::make_shared<SkilledDancer>(*this)));
        } else {
            dummy_g = false;
            ((SkilledDancer*)d.get())->dummy_g = false;
            std::cout << "Let's do an advanced dance" << std::endl;
        }       
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //all cases work fine
    basic->g(basic);
    advanced->g(advanced);
    basic->g(advanced); 
    advanced->g(basic);
}
```

Comment: Look up  double/multiple dispatch.

Comment: [OT]: You should remove `Dancer()` from `std::make_shared<Dancer>(Dancer())`

Comment: Thanks for telling me the name of the concept behind my issue. So if I understand correctly, there is no native support for multiple dispatch in c++ yet (the wikipedia article mentions dynamic cast of visitor pattern, but they do not seem to be pretty options).
Good call for the make_shared comment !

Comment: For Matrice inheritance, it is probably a bad idea, see [Circle-ellipse_problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem)

Comment: A triangular and a symmetric matrix are just data configurations of the same thing - a matrix. Whether the matrix is diagonal, symmetric, normalised, etc are simply computable attributes of the particular matrix configuration. This is not a problem that calls for polymorphism.

Comment: Yes, they could all be treated as a single matrix type, but there are optimisations to be had from treating them differently - for example if we know that half the matrix will be made up of zeros.

Comment: Agree with Neil's comment above but I'd pay attention as there is a potentially design issue there. What is the problem you want to solve? why having two g() methods in the 'SkilledDancer' class?

Comment: Let's say I have a formula which contains many types of matrices. The idea was to store  bases class pointers as leaves, so I would not care about the type of matrix in my expression tree.

Comment: @Kasper The two g() methods were simply examples of my reasoning showing that simple overload was not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you've just tried to do with your "dancers" example?

```
class Dancer
{
public:
    virtual void danceWith( Dancer * dancer ) {
        std::cout << "Let's do a basic dance" << std::endl;
    }
};

class SkilledDancer : public Dancer
{
public:
    void danceWith( Dancer * dancer ) override
    {
        if(auto skilledDancer = dynamic_cast< SkilledDancer*>(dancer)) {
            danceWith(skilledDancer);
        } else {
            Dancer::danceWith(dancer);
        }
    }

    void danceWith( SkilledDancer * dancer ) {
        std::cout << "Let's do an advanced dance" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Later:

```
Dancer* basic = new Dancer;
SkilledDancer* advanced = new SkilledDancer;
Dancer* pretending = advanced;

basic   ->danceWith(basic);         // -> Let's do a basic dance
advanced->danceWith(advanced);      // -> Let's do an advanced dance
basic   ->danceWith(advanced);      // -> Let's do a basic dance
advanced->danceWith(basic);         // -> Let's do a basic dance
advanced->danceWith(pretending);    // -> Let's do an advanced dance
```

Basically, we just use the fact that compiler always chooses the function overload fitting the most in terms of arguments. In the `SkilledDancer` class: For all `SkilledDancer*` typed arguments the second overload of `danceWith()` is be called (and it is decided on compile time - no polymorphic casts overheads). Meanwhile, all `Dancer*` typed arguments require runtime check and the overridden `danceWith()` is called. Check is performed and than an appropriate version of `danceWith()` to call is chosen. If the dancer is basic - dance basic, if he is just pretending - dance advanced.